# C# Generic object instantiation with generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I'm working on a generic delegate function and declaring a return type of type List.

```
public static List<T> PerformOperationOnGenericArray<T>(IList<T> myList,
    FunctionForGenericArray<T> operation)
```

Am I able to use a generic return type instead of List that also specifies a generic type, i.e. S

```
public static S<T> PerformOperationOnGenericArray<T, S>(IList<T> myList, 
    FunctionForGenericArray<T> operation)
```

I'm guessing that this is not possible but I cannot see the reason as to why not. The compiler surely knows the type when I specify:

```
PerformOperationOnGenericArray<int, List<string>>(myInts, i => i.Equals(12));
```

Is this perhaps a situation whereby I need to look at using dynamic types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use an open generic type as a generic type parameter, however, you can use a specific type `S<T>` as a parameter:

```
public static R PerformOperationOnGenericArray<T,R>
           (IList<T> myList, FunctionForGenericArray<T> operation) 
    where R : S<T>
```

In your case, if the type `S` is a fully defined (closed type) at compiled time, you don't even need to do that:

```
public static S<T> PerformOperationOnGenericArray<T>
           (IList<T> myList, FunctionForGenericArray<T> operation)
```

should be sufficient.

You only need to use the first form if `S` itself will vary. So what do I mean by this. Let's look at an example. If you have:

```
class Foo<T> { }
```

you can write:

```
public static Foo<T> PerformOperationOnGenericArray<T>
           (IList<T> myList, FunctionForGenericArray<T> operation)
```

But, if you have some group of related generic types:

```
class Foo<T> { }
class Bar<T> : Foo<T> { }
class Baz<T> : Foo<T> { }
```

and you want to allow the caller to specify which one to use, then you need to make the return type part of the generic signature of the method:

```
public static R PerformOperationOnGenericArray<T,R>
           (IList<T> myList, FunctionForGenericArray<T> operation) 
    where R : Foo<T>
```

where callers will now need to specify the type of `R` explicitly:

```
PerformOperationOnGenericArray<T,Bar<T>>( ... )
```

If you want to allow **any** generic type that accepts a single parameter to be allowed, there you are out of luck. The type system doesn't provide a way to express the restriction:

*`allow any generic type that allows a single parameter, and enforce that parameter to be a T`*

The best you can do is to define a well known interface that all known types conform to (like `IEnumerable<T>`, or one you craft yourself), and use that as part of the generic constraint:

```
public static R PerformOperationOnGenericArray<T,R>
           (IList<T> myList, FunctionForGenericArray<T> operation) 
    where R : IEnumerable<T>
```

However, in this case, the types supplied must all implement this interface. If you're looking for the former (where you can specify any type that just has to match on the number of type parameters) you're looking for generic [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)<sup>(1)</sup> - which C# doesn't support.

An interesting side note on this. Creating a generic method whose types cannot be inferred by the compiler solely from the formal parameters of the method is something to try to avoid. When the parameters cannot be inferred, the caller is forced to specify *all of the type parameters* - which leads to confusing and verbose code. While sometimes these situations do come up, you're better off trying to avoid them, where possible.

*<sup>(1)</sup>* - <sub>C# does support duck typing in anonymous types within a single assembly if the types match in the order, types, and names of their members - upon which the compiler will assume that they are the same type.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I have tried your second suggestion and the compiler doesn't like S. I get "Unknown Entity 'S'"

Comment: @Ryan - the second form requires that `S` be an actual type. It's not meant to be a type parameter. If `S` is itself a type parameter, then you **must** use the first form. I'll update my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Ah..sorry I misread what you were saying. That makes sense now thank you for the clarification.

This isn't something that is going to production. Just looking at the bounds of generic typing on delegate functions.